# How can I post form data from react to an express.js server and use it as part of a url string

Tags: reactjs, express, post, fetch

Just to make this clearer. I have a form where the user inputs a name which is passed to the apiUrl const to become part of the URL string. The form input data is passed through state as {this.state.input}. After the user inputs the form with the name he wants to search for, he clicks a button which calls the onButtonSubmit function  that fetches the data with the updated apiUrl parameters. The catch is, this is running on the front-end and as this is a proprietary api, I don't want to expose the api key (which is part of the url) to the user.

I have set up an express.js server but I'm still unsure on how I can post the form data to it and then use that in the same manner used in my code below.

```
onButtonSubmit = () => {
      const apiUrl = 'URLStringPart1' + this.state.input + 'URLStringpart2withAPIKey';
      fetch(apiUrl)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
          result => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              array1: result.array1,
              array2: result.array2,
              array3: result.array3,
              array4: result.array4,
              array5: result.array5,      
              route: 'fetched'
            });
          },
          error => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: false,
              error: error
            });
          }
        );
    }
```

So the output I'm looking for would follow something like this:

1. Post form data from frontend after the user submits it with a
   button click
2. Through the backend, after the form data is posted, use it to update the apiurl and then fetch the data from the api(using axios perhaps)
3. Send the fetched data back to the frontend

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use prams,  in your express server the API route should look like this: api/users/:name --> returns user with this name.
Then try fetching this API by sending the request to the server like this:
`http://locahost:8000/api/users/${this.state.name}`